# Invalid operation when glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) in pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Code:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def draw():
    pass

def main():
    glutInit()
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
    glutCreateWindow('Demo')
    glutDisplayFunc(draw)
    glutMainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\test.py", line 10, in main
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "D:\Program\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 230, in glCheckError
    raise self._errorClass(
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1282,
        description = b'\xce\xde\xd0\xa7\xb2\xd9\xd7\xf7',
        baseOperation = glEnable,
        cArguments = (GL_MULTISAMPLE,)
)
```

The error description is "Invalid operation".

I'm studying OpenGL and I want to try anti-aliasing. I don't known why this not work. How should I solve this? How to find that is there any environment problem? Or maybe I made some low-level mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling OpenGL commands is only valid when a valid OpenGL context exists. When working with glut, the context is created by the `glutCreateWindow` command. All methods called before that will throw an error because the context isn't valid.

Correct code:

```
glutInit()
glutCreateWindow('Demo')
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
glutDisplayFunc(draw)
glutMainLoop()
```